# How to support UTF-8 in TCPDF?

Tags: php, tcpdf

I have make one pdf using UTF-8 character. but, not working utf-8 in tcpdf.

**CODE:**

```
<?php
require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf_import.php');

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
$pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 008');
$pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

// set default header data

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

// get esternal file content
$utf8text = "私、本書に署名する目的は、法律で認められている最大範囲において、SNUBA ガイド、";

// set color for text
$pdf->SetTextColor(0, 63, 127);

//Write($h, $txt, $link='', $fill=0, $align='', $ln=false, $stretch=0, $firstline=false, $firstblock=false, $maxh=0)

// write the text
$pdf->Write(5, $utf8text, '', 0, '', false, 0, false, false, 0);


// ---------------------------------------------------------

//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('example_008.pdf', 'I');
?>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
????????????????????????????????SNUBA ????
```

I have to create one pdf. Pdf is working but not support other utf-8 character. How to make utf-8 supported pdf using tcpdf?

Comment: Are you sure your PHP source file is saved with the correct encoding?  It could be the string literal inside the script is already mangled.  Also I seem to recall PHP does not have the best Unicode support.  Also, be sure the font used inside the PDF contains the characters you wish to display.

Comment: I also have the same problem, Bharat Chauhan did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using the wrong font.
I had the same problem and then I change the font from 'helvetica' to 'dejavusans' and it started working.

Comment: It worked also for Slovenian language. Thx

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code, since I had problems printing Japanese characters, and the result was the same on my website too.

The problem is the font.

I was already using the `dejavu` font, which is great for latin and other characters, but it doesn't contain CJK characters. For printing such characters you need a specific CJK font, or one of the few pan-Unicode font available.

Some examples are: `Arial Unicode MS`, `Cyberbit`

Unfortunately, they are not free, and require a license.